# Limit Comparison Test for integral

Tags: calculus, limits

Qs: Use the limit comparison test to determine whether the following integrals converge

$$\int_{x=0}^\infty \frac{x^\frac{1}{3}+5}{x^2-6x+10}$$

---

I did the question and found that it diverges, but it turns out this integral converges by the Limit Comparison Test.

My Answer: f(x) = (the equation above) and g(x) = $\frac{1}{x^\frac{5}{3}}$

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)/g(x) = 1$$
which is positive and finite.

$$\int_{x=0}^\infty \frac{1}{x^\frac{5}{3}} diverges$$

So by the LCT, my original integral diverges

---

However, this integral converges by the LCT and I just don't see how.
Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the exact statement of the limit comparison for integral you have in your mind? Because $g(x) = x^{-5/3}$ only tells the asymptotic behavior of your integrand $f(x)$ for large $x$, hence the behavior of $g(x)$ near $x = 0$ is *completely irrelevant* to that of $f$.

Comment: Very sorry for my late reply. So, I wanted to show that the integrand $f(x)$ above converges on the range $[0,inf)$. Therefore, I need to have a function $g(x)$ that also converges on this integral. That is why behaviour of $g(x)$ near $x=0$ mattered for me. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is that, look at the neighborhood of $x=0$, the integrand is continuous, so just split it:
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^{1/3}+5}{x^{2}-6x+10}dx=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{x^{1/3}+5}{x^{2}-6x+10}dx+\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^{1/3}+5}{x^{2}-6x+10}dx,
\end{align*}
and 
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{x^{1/3}+5}{x^{2}-6x+10}dx
\end{align*}
exists by the continuity of $\dfrac{x^{1/3}+5}{x^{2}-6x+10}$ on the compact set $[0,1]$.

Now use Limit Comparison Test to $1/x^{5/3}$ on $[1,\infty)$ to conclude that
\begin{align*}
\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^{1/3}+5}{x^{2}-6x+10}dx
\end{align*}
exists.

Comment: I understand the 2nd half, about using LCT for [1,inf). However, I am a bit confused as to why the first integral from [0,1] exists.

Comment: The integrand is continuous, it has no singularity.

Comment: It is simply the usual Riemann integration, not improper Riemann for that.

Comment: In fact, the answers I have did the LCT for [1,inf) then straight away said that the integral exists for [0,inf). I'm guessing that's the extra it missed out, but I have never seen this theorem. Is there an easier way to explain it?

Comment: Ah right I think I understand now. Would the method of splitting up the integral be best then, for limits of [0,inf)?

Comment: Because the LCT you have used has singularity at $x=0$ but the original integrand has no singularity at $x=0$, so splitting the domain of integration is then the second step to consider.

Comment: Oh ok. So my reasoning for this would be that the LCT is only for g(x) non-negative for all x>=0. However my g(x) is not defined at x=0, so we cannot use it. Therefore, we restrict the domain from 1 to inf and use LCT. Then show the part you have left converges.